# 'ContentView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Tags: swiftui

swift ui で

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
ContentView()
}
}

に対して

'ContentView' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

と

Missing argument for parameter 'pinned' in call

Insert 'pinned: <#[String]#>

というアラートが出ます。

アクセス private を除いても出ます。

どこがちがうでしょうか？

pinnedは空の配列です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContentView(pined: [])`とかにすればうまくいくと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。